# SSH to private host via a public server

Tags: ssh

I develop IoT hubs running Linux where I’d like to access them via SSH over the internet for development. They are often placed in remote locations. It seems the E3372 modem I use isn’t able to port forward unless I download and install some software from an untrusted source.

I wonder is there a way or a service that would let me connect to a device not visible on the internet (has an internet connection) via a server such as AWS?

The hub might also connect to the server periodically to see if there’s a connection request and then the connection is made by the mutually accessible server?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can make an outbound SSH connection with a `RemoteForward` tunnel back to the IoT device.

**[image: ⚠] Do this *only* for development, never production; your server is vulnerable to your users.**

From the IoT device, run:

```sh
sleeptime=5
while sleep $sleeptime; do
  start=$(date +%s)
  ssh -N -i /path/to/unlocked/ssh/key \
    -R 1234:localhost:22 phone-home-user@phone-home.example.com
  if [ $(date +%s) -gt $((start + 600)) ] || [ $sleeptime -ge 81920 ]; then
    sleeptime=5
  else
    sleeptime=$((sleeptime*2))
  fi
done
```

I've performed a minimal effort not to loop endlessly when there are connectivity issues, but you'll likely want to do more. This sleeps for 5 seconds, saves the time, runs ssh (see below), and checks the time again. If it's >600s later, reset the sleep timer to 5s. Otherwise, double that timer up to a day (5s, 10s, 20s, 40s, 80s, 160s, 5m, 10m, 20m, 40m, 1.5h, 3h, 6h, 12h, 1d, repeat).

**Warning, this solution is as fickle as the reliability of that ssh connection.**

The `ssh` command uses:

- `-N`: Do not execute a remote command, just forward ports and stay opened
- `-i KEY`: Use this key to authenticate (do not password-protect that key)
- `-R 1234:localhost:22`: connections to the *remote* host are forwarded to the IoT device's ssh server

On `phone-home.example.com`, add a `phone-home-user` and lock down its shell so it can't do anything but connect and port-forward (this will let a savvy user forward whatever they want —from your server's LAN— so be careful). Add the key's public side to that user's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Now you can ssh into `phone-home.example.com` and then run `ssh -p 1234 localhost` to get to that host. (You could use `ssh` flag `-g` for global port forwards to connect from your system rather than jumping through the phone home server, but I don't recommend that since it means anybody else can too.)

If you want to support *multiple* hosts, you'll either need a system to map the ports to each dev IoT system or else consider a remote socket (see `-R remote_socket:host:hostport` in `man ssh`). I suspect sockets are vastly superior here.

**[image: ⚠] Don't forget: When development completes, *revoke that key!***
(remove it from `authorized_keys`)

Also monitor your phone home server's SSH logs for connection/authentication issues and ideally have a way of reaching out to that system's operator (e.g. using more sensible accounts than "phone-home-user").